# Perform "Left/Right/Inner" joins with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I come from an SQL background and have been finding it difficult building queries with mongoose.

I have a group schema that looks like this :

```
var groupSchema = new Schema({
  title:{type:String, index:true, unique: true, required:true, lowercase:true}
});
```

and two other schemas, documents, and Users, that reference the `groupSchema`

User Schema:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  //Other datas
  group: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group'}],

});
```

Documents Schema:

```
var documentSchema = new Schema({
    ownerId:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref:"User"},
    group:{ type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"Group", required:true},

});
```

I would like to `fetch all group data and populate them with the documents that belong to that group`. I tried using the populate query but it did not work

Comment: The most common mistake made by people coming from an SQL background is to build schemas which depend heavily on JOINs with other collections. The reason is that MongoDB [only has very rudimentary JOIN support](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). You should try to embed the relevant information into the document instead of referencing another collection.

Comment: Please provide all code you used for populate. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html. if I had to guess you're not registering your model to the mongoose connection, but I can't know that without the full code you used.

Comment: Best learning case here is to turn on "debugging" output which will log all queries actually being issued to the database. `mongoose.set("debug",true)`. Then you will see for yourself that these are **not** in fact "JOINS", but just seperate queries being issued to the database. The other point here is due to your defined references you in fact want the "reverse", being *"fetch all 'document' data an populate from the 'group'"*. But really a document database such as MongoDB is not a relational database, and should not be used as one.